# Part for VHF/FM booster?

Tags: schematics, amplifier, components, frequency-modulation

I'm needing to create a booster and the easiest schematic I've found is this: http://electronics-diy.com/500mW_FM_VHF_Transmitter_Amplifier_Booster.php however, they do not document what part they use for the amp. Does anyone know what amp they may use? Or a similarly easy way to create booster inexpensively?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [MAX2650](http://datasheets.maxim-ic.com/en/ds/MAX2650.pdf) LNA (Low Noise Amplifier) is not the amplifier they are using, but it may be suitable, depending on the **gain** you want. The MAX2650 has a gain of 18.3dB at 900MHz. If you need higher gain you can cascade a couple of them.

The one in the schematic you linked to is an **MMIC** (Monolithic Microwave IC), like Leon says. MMICs often consist of just a couple of transistors. This is a typical MMIC package:

[image: MMIC package] [image: MMIC]

Notice that it has two ground pins on opposite sides for improved PCB layout, but that also means that the power supply has to share a pin with the output. The MAX2650 comes in a SOT-143 package and has separate pins for these.

[image: SOT-143 package]

Comment: What exactly is the purpose of the link?

Comment: @Earlz - Oops, my bad! :-) Fixed.

Comment: Ok much better. I'm stilling learning about how this will work and build it, but out of curiosity, do you think this would require a heatsink? My gut instinct is no, but I can't quite tell how much 320mW might be

Comment: @Earlz - The MAX2650 comes in a SOT143 SMT package, so you can't mount a heatsink on it. You do want lots of copper though, for shielding, and that will also work as a heatsink.

Answer (score 1):

It's an MMIC. At VHF virtually anything should do, such as the $1.25 [MCL MAR-1+](http://www.minicircuits.com/pdfs/MAR-1+.pdf). I've constructed similar amplifiers by mounting the parts directly on a scrap of PCB material.

Comment: Upvoted because it's you who tossed the term "MMIC", and both other answers refer to it. Still I think your answers are often a bit too brief. You don't even say what MMIC stands for, for instance.

Comment: @stevenvh, Google can easily find the definition of MMIC, so that's trivial. The answer is adequate for a specific pragmatic question for someone who is familiar with RF topics (as someone plans on building a VHF RF amplifier from a schematic should be).

Answer (score 1):

As Leon says - MMIC is the name you want.
Go to 
[Digikey](http://www.digikey.com)
  and search for MMIC and go from there.

For the same pinout style you could use

[NLB310 data sheet](http://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/RFMD%20PDFs/NLB-310.pdf)

[In stock at Digikey](http://search.digikey.com/scripts/DkSearch/dksus.dll?Detail&name=689-1004-1-ND) for $US3.44 in ones.

That's a 10 GHz part !!!
You can get functionally similar ones for under $US1 with lower bandwidths.

That's known as a Micro-X 4 package.

Digikey has about 5 different parts available in 1's in stock.

Surprisingly, I find that the one I listed above is the cheapest Micro-X 4 available in 1's and in stock.

If you are willing to go to a different package, same principle otherwise, there are many more available.

Cheapest is BGU7031 from NXP. 1 GHz.

- [Datasheet](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/BGU7031.pdf) in a SOT363-g pkg
- [Pricing](http://search.digikey.com/scripts/DkSearch/dksus.dll?Detail&name=568-5506-1-ND) 48 cents in ones. 14.5 cents at 10k

They say

1.2 Features and benefits

- Internally biased
- Flat gain between 40 MHz and 1 GHz
- Noise figure of 4.5 dB
- High linearity with an IP3O of 29 dBm
- 75 Ω input and output impedance
- ESD protection > 2 kV Human Body Model (HBM) on all pins

1.3 Applications

- Terrestrial and cable Set-Top Boxes (STB)
- Silicon and “Can” tuners
- Personal and Digital Video Recorders (PVR and DVR)
- Home networking and in-house signal distribution